# Treating null filter values as "any" when filtering on multiple columns in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, filter, sqlalchemy, sql-null

We are trying to implement the ability to search across multiple (or all) columns on joined tables in our database, but with the requirement that an arbitrary number of columns can actually be left "blank" (null) to mean "any value".

The tables can consist of 1:1, 1:Many, and Many:Many relationships, meaning that it can be problematic to try to filter on a single column at a time using `Query.filter()`.

Here is an example of what our DB might look like:

#### **Car**

| id | color | fuel_remaining |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Red' | 14 |
| 2 | 'Blue' | 17 |

#### **Passengers**

| id | name | age | favorite_food | car_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Sue' | 24 | 'spaghetti' | 1 |
| 2 | 'Todd' | 17 | 'oranges' | 1 |
| 3 | 'Allison' | 52 | 'pumpkin pie' | 1 |
| 4 | 'Todd' | 44 | 'spaghetti' | 2 |
| 5 | 'Allison' | 36 | 'nachos' | 2 |
| 6 | 'Stephen' | 46 | 'turkey' | 2 |

Some examples of the types of searches we want to support:

- *Example A* - "Find all Car.id where at least one passenger's favorite food is spaghetti." (Expected: `[1, 2]`).
- *Example B* - "Find all Car.id where there is a passenger named Sue and a passenger named Stephen." (Expected: `[]`).
- *Example C* - "Find all Car.id where there is a passenger named Allison (age 52) and a passenger named Todd (age 17)." (Expected: `[1]`).

Is there a way to do this with SQLAlchemy, such that we can simply write out the code for a single query and set of filters that covers all of the possible columns we wish to filter by and then ignores any columns where the filter value for that column is `None`?

Our current method has been to try to map the search criteria as pydantic BaseModel and then append filters on that model that are "valid" (non-null). So first we create a basic query:

```py
car = Car(id=1, color='Red')
passenger_a = Passenger(name='Allison', age=52)
passenger_b = Passenger(name='Todd', age=17)

new_query = session.query(Car.id)
```

Then we start adding filters dynamically per column if the value of that column is not null in the pydantic BaseModel we are using as our search criteria.

Note that `my_orm_models.py` contains SQLAlchemy Base ORM classes (e.g `class Car(Base)`, `class Passenger(Base)`)

```py
new_query = filter_non_null(query=new_query, orm_model=car, orm_class="Car")
new_query = filter_non_null(query=new_query, orm_model=passenger_a, orm_class="Passenger")
new_query = filter_non_null(query=new_query, orm_model=passenger_b, orm_class="Passenger")
```

Where `filter_non_null` looks like this:

```py
import my_orm_models

def filter_non_null(query: Query, orm_model: BaseModel, orm_class: str) -> Query:
    orm_model_type = getattr(my_orm_models, orm_class)
    for k, v in orm_model.dict().items():
        if v is not None:
            field = getattr(orm_model_type, k)
            query = query.filter(field == v)

    return query
```

Obviously this implementation runs into issues as soon as we need to try to do something like *Example C* above, where we want to retrieve a car where each passenger is filtered on a set of AND column values.

Any ideas would be welcomed, either to try to improve our current implementation or outright replace it with another method.

Comment: The expected result for example B seems to contradict the data provided, seems that it should be `[1]`.

Comment: Fixed the example, thanks!